# How to get DropDownList items when submit?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following details in my project

**MODEL**

```
  public class AnimalModels
  {
    public string AnimalId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> AnimalList { get; set; }
  }
```

**VIEW**

```
@model DropDownList.Models.AnimalModels

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Animal/Index.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <div>
    <fieldset>
      <div>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnimalId)</div>
      <div>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AnimalId, Model.AnimalList)</div>
      <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AnimalId)</div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
  public class AnimalController : Controller
  {
    //
    // GET: /Animal/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      AnimalModels model = new AnimalModels();
      model.AnimalList = new List<SelectListItem>();
      return View(model);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(AnimalModels model)
    {
      //TODO: get animal list
      model.AnimalList = new List<SelectListItem>();
      return View(model);
    }

  }
```

**Index.js**

```
//[B]Document ready
$(document).ready(function () {
  //Populate ddl using ajax (jquery)
  $.ajax({
    url: 'Resources/Animals.xml',    // name of file with our data - link has been renamed
    dataType: 'xml',    // type of file we will be reading
    success: parse,     // name of function to call when done reading file
    error: showError    // name of function to call when failed to read
  });

});
//[E]Document ready

function parse(xmlDoc) {
  var options = new Array();
  $(xmlDoc).find("ITEMS").each(function () {
    $(this).find("ITEM").each(function () {
      var optionValue = $(this).find('VALUE').text();
      var optionLabel = $(this).find('TEXT').text();
      options.push('<option value="' + optionValue + '">' + optionLabel + '</option>');
    });
  });
  options = options.join('');
  $('#AnimalId').append(options);
}

var showError = function (xhr, status, err) {
  alert("Error loading file Animals.xml in Resources folder.\n" + xhr.status + " " + err + ".");
};
```

**Animals.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ITEMS>
    <ITEM>
        <VALUE>-1</VALUE>
        <TEXT></TEXT>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <VALUE>0</VALUE>
        <TEXT>Tiger</TEXT>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <VALUE>1</VALUE>
        <TEXT>Lion</TEXT>
    </ITEM>
</ITEMS>
```

my question is there any way to get all drop down list items when i hit submit button?
because the value is always null when i tried to debug it

[image]

Comment: As I understand you fill dropdown items collection on client side and want to get it back on server side after submitting? In this case answer - no, you can't do this. Dropdownlist (actually HTML SELECT element) sends on server only value of it's selected element.

Comment: what should i change to get all ddl items? could you give me an example?

Comment: Why you don't load DDL items in server-side?
AnimalModels model = new AnimalModels();
model.AnimalList = GetItemsFromResource();

Comment: i just try this AnimalModels model = new AnimalModels();
      model.AnimalList = new List<SelectListItem>();
      model.AnimalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Tiger" });
      model.AnimalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Lion" });
in GET index, but AnimalList still have null value when i POST it. could you shows me what wrong with my code?

Comment: You should make this in any actions where you return AnimalModel. ASP.NET MVC doesn't store any state like WebForms does, so you should always get all needed data on server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add into the form -

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.AnimalList.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.AnimalList[i].Value)
  @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.AnimalList[i].Text)
}
```

Comment: I already update the code (located under this answer post) in case someone have the same problems. hope that can help!

Answer (score 0):

Code solution suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2984635/user2984635

Model, index.js (unused), Animal.xml (unused) is remaining the same.

View and controller code are updated. bellow are the updates:

**VIEW**

```
@model DropDownList.Models.AnimalModels

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@*<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Animal/Index.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>*@

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <div>
    <fieldset>
      <div>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnimalId)</div>
      <div>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AnimalId, Model.AnimalList)</div>
      <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AnimalId)</div>
        //[B]the update
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.AnimalList.Count; i++) 
        { 
            @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.AnimalList[i].Value) 
            @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.AnimalList[i].Text) 
        }
        //[E]the update
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public class AnimalController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Animal/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            AnimalModels model = new AnimalModels();
            model = new AnimalModels(); 
            //[B]the update
            model.AnimalList = new List<SelectListItem>(); 
            model.AnimalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Tiger" }); 
            model.AnimalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Lion" });
            //[E]the update
            return View(model);
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Index(AnimalModels model)
        {
            //[B]the update
            model.AnimalList[int.Parse(model.AnimalId)].Selected = true;
            //[E]the update
            return View(model);
        }

}
```